# Get the title from the document that is loaded in a WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a textblock and a webbrowser control. I have a problem, for example, my webbrowser navigates to google.com. I want the textblock to change the title to google.com when webbrowser has navigated to google.com.

Please help me achieve this using c#.

Answer (score 6):

Tested with IE

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser LoadCompleted="webBrowser1_LoadCompleted" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="73,72,0,0" Name="webBrowser1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
    <Button Content="Go" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
private void webBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    this.Title = doc.Title;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com");
}
```

Without `dynamic` and hardly any exception handling:

```
private void webBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Object doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    this.Title = GetPropertyValue<string>(doc, "Title");
}

private T GetPropertyValue<T>(object obj, string propertyName)
{
    Type objectType = obj.GetType(); 
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = objectType.GetProperty(propertyName);
    Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
    if(propertyType == typeof(T))
    {
        object propertyValue = (T)info.GetValue(obj, null);   
        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Property " + propertyName + " is not of type " + T);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't this also be done with a binding? Like `<Window Title={Binding Path=Title}>` and then set the window's context to the browser or something like that? Or you could probably name the WebBrowser and not set the window's DataContext.

Comment: If you mean `Title="{Binding ElementName=webBrowser1, Path=Document.Title}"` then no, not as far as I know because the Title property of the document does not raise PropertyChanged so the binding would not be updated.

Comment: Changed example to use LoadCompleted instead of Navigated

Comment: LoadCompleted will not refresh on title being set dynamically via javascript etc

Comment: Of course that is something that is nearly impossible to detect.

Comment: What classes could I use instead of DYNAMIC type?

Comment: @Doug - I added an example without `dynamic`. Warning: I left out exceptionhandling and I didn't test this.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract title tag from webBrowser's `Text` property, just subscribe to `LoadCompleted` event

Comment: There is no Text property. But the LoadCompleted is better than the Navigated. I will update my code.

Comment: oops looks like I forgot exact name. Anyway Erno's solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with Document.Title property, as if title has been set or changed as in javascript, you will not get the latest value once set.

Instead of using default Web Browser in WPF, we are using FormsHost and we use Windows Form's Web Browser which supports property as DocumentTitle and an event of DocumentTitleChanged.

So I will suggest using following control and you can use more functionality available in forms version. If you notice carefully, both function exactly same performance wise as both create a win32 control and interact with it.

```
public class FormsWebBrowser : 
    System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost
{

    System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser Browser = 
        new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();

    public FormsWebBrowser()
    {
        Child = Browser;
        Browser.DocumentTitleChanged += 
            new EventHandler(Browser_DocumentTitleChanged);
    }

    void Browser_DocumentTitleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DocumentTitle = Browser.DocumentTitle;
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// This will let you bind
    ///</summary>
    public string DocumentTitle
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DocumentTitleProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(DocumentTitleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentTitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DocumentTitle", typeof(string), 
        typeof(FormsWebBrowser), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(""));
}
```

It might need some more code to implement little extra but everything is possible by adding more dependency properties and controlling the logic.

Answer (score 0):

This one will work

```
var docTitle = document.getElementsByTagName("title")
        .Cast<IHTMLElement>()
        .FirstOrDefault().innerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just little typo fixups for answer above Erno de Weerd, for .NET 4.5
*) property name is IHTMLDocument2_nameProp
*) fix in typo in if block

```
  private void webBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Object doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    this.Title = GetPropertyValue<string>(doc, "IHTMLDocument2_nameProp");
}

private T GetPropertyValue<T>(object obj, string propertyName)
{
    Type objectType = obj.GetType(); 
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = objectType.GetProperty(propertyName);
    Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
    if(propertyType == typeof(T))
    {
        object alue = (T)propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);   
        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Property " + propertyName + " is not of type " + T);
    }
}
```